# Mouseover actions in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, mouseover

How can we implement mouseover actions in Reporting Services?

E.g.: in a graph, if I take my mouse pointer to the X,Y intersection, then it should display the value. How can I do this?

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING.  All uppercase characters are generally taken to be symbolic of shouting on the web.  I think you'll get a better response to your question if you edit it to use mixed case.

Comment: Press the caps lock key before posting again, please.

Comment: thanks @mmyers, my eyes feel much better now.

Comment: i am really sorry for that....i new to posting the question's on the web

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it is not possible to handle general mouse over events. Reporting services is not a full programming environment after all.

Unfortunately according to [this article](http://support.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1052) it is not possible to have datapoint tooltips in Dundas for SSRS at all.

The best alternative is to turn on Labels in the report properties. This will show the data point value on the chart itself, next to the Point.

Comment: I AM USING DUNDAS CHARTS ONLY WHERE SHOULD I SET PROPERTY? I AM USING SSRS 2005?

Comment: I AM USING STACKED CHART CONTROL

Comment: actually I am mistaken. The tooltip property only works for Dundas charts in ASP.NET and Webforms. Not reporting service..

Comment: is there any way to achieve this in ssrs?

Comment: No. According to Dundas it is impossible to do this do due a design limitation in Reporting Services